# Multiplayer player 2 player game

Tags: php, flash, multiplayer

I would like to create a chess multiplayer game,1player vs 1player .

I will use flash for animations and client and a server-side language for checking if the moves are correct, record each player action to a database, decide winner and give some credits to the winner.

My main programming language is PHP and I will have someone do the flash work depending on my directions.

I would like to know if anybody tried to do this before , or if you have any tutorial, guide, steps to follow when developing p2p games ? I want to do this efficiently and to be able to support up to at least 100 players on a VDS with 512 RAM .

I am planning to have the game work like this :

1) Initialise variables like credits, player names inside the flash client , after retrieving them from php

2) Start the game

3) If I am player2 and player1 is thinking of a decision, the flash client will send requests to the PHP file to check the database if player1 made any decision. If so, it will be my turn to do a decision and move a piece

4) When my turn comes , no requests are sent to the PHP anymore, until I want to move a piece . When I try to do that ,it sends a request and the PHP will check if my move is valid, and return some variables that flash will use to show error or move pointer back to player1

The game will also have a timer that will sync with PHP. Each player can think 20 seconds to do a move.

1)Any suggestions for my implementation ?What im looking for are suggestions to improve efficiency on this and reduce server load and if someone ever had any experience with a similar project, how did they do it, or how would they do it ?

2)My implementation of periodical HTTP requests isnt such a good idea, because I know that the server can become overloaded, I'd like to know if someone can suggest any alternative but secure option . 100 users at the same time would mean about 100 HTTP requests/second. Is that a number that a VDS can handle for days ?

---

Later Edit :

After the replies that I got on this post , I came to the conclusion that using sockets instead of HTTP requests every second would be the best idea to use when waiting for a move on the opposite player.

My game would have 100 tables available for players, with 1 socket for communication and 1 port for each table . So 1 socket with 100 ports. PHP will communicate to flash the socket and port for the table , when the game starts and the initialisation variables are sent.

I plan to use flash to listen to the socket server and see what happens when the opposite player must move .

When I move , flash will check if the move is valid from it's side, then send data to PHP . PHP will return OK or NOT and will also update the data on the socket port.

About the socket , Im not sure javascript would be a good option for this, so Im thinking about PHP sockets or JAVA sockets.

PHP sockets seem to be my first option , due to familiarity with the language.
My 2nd would be to rent a smartfoxserver and my 3rd would be to use the services of Player.IO.
Im planing to create a very nice game and sell it. The graphics are pretty much done and they look great. The hardest part is doing this efficiently and easy to install after.

---

Thank you for your time ! Regards

Comment: `I would like to know if anybody tried to do this before` Tried to create a chess game?

Comment: Yes , but I gave a larger description of my project

Comment: The game must be secure and communicate with the server, which will check if every move is correct and more .

Comment: It sounds like you have a decent plan... so what are you asking about exactly? I have never done anything like this in particular but of course it will be possible.  You want to have the flash poll the server for the most recent move and if that was done by the player asking then it is the other player's turn still.  The key to designing this will be that http is stateless so all the info needed will have to be handed each time (not the whole history of the game but some game id, users, etc.)  Check out RESTful programming interfaces for help on server side design for this project. good luck!

Comment: My implementation of periodical HTTP requests isnt such a good idea, because I know that the server can become overloaded, I'd like to know if someone can suggest any alternative but secure option . I mean that when it's not my turn to move pieces, sending requests every second can even get a browser stuck.

Comment: What im looking for are suggestions to improve efficiency on this and reduce server load and if someone ever had any experience with a similar project, how did they do it, or how would they do it ?

Comment: Have the HTTP requests sent on an event (e.g. a user makes a move) rather than every second?

Comment: nomaD ... if I must move a piece, after I move it only then FLASH sends data to the PHP file. But if it's not my turn, how would I know when my turn comes ? We have to listen to the socket or send requests every second ...

Answer (score 2):

The server load for a game like this should be really minimal.  If you're using flash, I would take advantage of the socket object and just open a socket to your server, that way you don't need to pester it with questions about what has changed... it will notify the clients when/if something noteworthy has.
Otherwise your plan is a pretty good one, so, you'll probably have to ask some specific questions about things that you're stumped by.

If you REALLY want to reduce server load, write the chess logic in the flash client and let IT decide if an attempted move (by the player) is illegal, or if the player has lost or whatnot... use the server strictly for message relay and data storage.

Comment: Hi,The game logic will be written both in flash and server. I cannot trust any data coming from flash . Anyone can simulate my client, or decompile it and send malicious data. Socket seems to be the solution of getting out of the HTTP requests.

Comment: i have an doubt same 1vs1 chess game i am planning to build .my concern is how can show opponent move to player 1. do i have to use a database to store moves and send it to client by node? or  2. is there any other procedure to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes a mistake to design a project around what you have available, such as PHP knowledge and access to a server with 512 MB of RAM. There are a lot of projects where you should consider your resources first, but an independent, first time game project isn't one of them.

Even though your primary language is PHP, you shouldn't restrict yourself from working on the Flash portion yourself. Also, using a web server and database as a communication method for a multiplayer game will result in some very clunky behavior.

You aren't limited by your VDS either. You can use a micro instance on [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/) for [free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) for a year. If setting up an EC2 server from scratch seems daunting, there are [tutorials](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/setting-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2-in-5-minutes/) all over the internet that take you from start to finish.

The front end of your game can be written in Javascript or Flash AS3. There are a lot of game development libraries available for both. [Flixel](http://www.flixel.org), [Flashpunk](http://www.flashpunk.net), and [PushButton](http://pushbuttonengine.com/) are free AS3 game libraries. [MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org) is a Javascript/HTML5 game library. All of them have extensive documentation and a good community.

You can write the server backend using [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org) and use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to handle your game communications, even if you don't know anything about packets -- or you could use something like [Player.IO](http://playerio.com/) if you want to pay a little money and have an outside service worry about that for you.

If you write the backend properly, one hundred users won't be a problem for your server. You'll need to start thinking about new hardware when you get in the thousands.

And since you're looking for general game making advice, start reading articles on blogs like [#AltDevBlogADay](http://altdevblogaday.com/). You'll pick up a lot of insight on design from other people passionate about games.

Comment: Hi,Your reply is something I was waiting for. How about if Id still use PHP for sending the initialisation vars at start , then use JAVA for server-side and for the actual game logic (calculate if a move is valid , decide winner) and use JAVA sockets to communicate with flash about the opposite player moves. This would make the application strong enough I'd say.

Comment: About sockets . My knowledge is that PHP can also work with sockets , but I dont know too much about them . I know this is a stupid question, but do I have to open a socket for each game table ? And pass the socket to flash using PHP when game starts ?

Comment: You only need to use one socket for each client. The client should have a single connection object used for sending and receiving, which you would initialize using the address of the server. If you're going to use PHP sockets for your server, you aren't going to be using a webserver like Apache to serve that code -- you'll be writing your own server using PHP. Read this tutorial for more information: http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/ However, if you aren't already familiar with using PHP this way, I still recommend node.js. There are a lot of great tutorials available.

Comment: So basically if I have 1 game table with 2 players at that table, I would need 2 sockets . And when player1 makes a move, I would serve data to the socket for player2, right ?

Comment: Yes and no, depending on what you mean by sockets. Each player communicates by a socket connection when the server is running, but they are both communicating using the same socket code. Over the socket, the server can receive a player message that contains the table name, the player name, the move, and possibly some sort of authentication, then send that information to the other player at that table. You could think of a socket like a telephone line, and the server as someone that routes calls. Both players call the server, keep the line open, and the server relays messages between them.

Comment: As an addendum, this is just how the communication for player moves can work. There is obviously more complicated logic than message passing going on. For example, a player may need to send an alert later on when it receives an invalid move, to request the other player send it again, or possibly to inform the server that something is wrong with the game. The majority of game communication will be client to client, but you'll need to write logic for other activities as well, such as creating new tables, joining games, viewing a list of tables, etc. This can all happen over the same socket.

Comment: i have an doubt same 1vs1 chess game i am  planning to build my concern is how can show opponent move to player   do i have to use a database to store moves and send it to client by node? or is there any other procedure to do?